# Query to reduce column length

Tags: postgresql, postgis, pgadmin-4

I'm new to PostgreSQL so sorry if I haven't explained myself clearly!

I've used the below query to find out the max character length of each column in my table. I now want to be able to shorten each column to the largest character length. Can anyone help?

```
SELECT
        MAX(char_length(gid)) as column1,
        MAX(char_length(column2)) as column2
FROM
        schema.table
```

The reason I want to do this I want to export to shapefiles and the file size is huge as the majority of the columns are set to 254.

Comment: What data types does these columns have now? If they are `char(254)` alter them to `varchar(254)`. *I want to export to shapefiles* How do you do it?

Comment: What **is** the current maximum length of the values? If you want to reduce the size, you can run an UPDATE statement, e.g. `update the_table set column2 = substr(column2, 1, 20)` to shorten the string to 20 characters - but that sounds like a terrible idea.

Comment: @Akina So they're currently varchar if I look in pgAdmin. I load the table into QGIS using the PostGIS database link. From here I can use QGIS to export as a shapefile which the column types are now 254 strings. (I don't know the difference between char & string sorry?)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name just out of interest why do you think that sounds like a terrible idea?

Comment: Because you are removing data without checking if it's OK to remove parts of the column value. Especially if the contents has some structure - which I assume as you talk about a "shapes". If you change e.g. the string `'point(1,2)'` to `'point(1'` what does that give you?

Comment: But it sounds as if you think that the column _definition_ has any influence on the size of the actual data **in the column**. If you export a column that's defined as `varchar(2000)` that contains a single character, that export will only contain a single character - not 2000

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I know what the column values are used for and I'm not worried about that.  The problem with trying to explain this is the crossover with GIS. I understand that this isn't a problem for the data held in the Postgres database but the problem is exporting that data to shapefile.

Comment: So wherever you uses the export, can handle `'point(1,2)'` just as well as `'point(1'`?

Comment: Recommendation. Obtain max lengths by the query you show. Create source table temporary copy. Alter fields lengths according to max data lengths obtained. Export data. Delete temporary copy. Does the exporting file decreases? Does the data is consistent and non-truncated?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name No that would cause problems but I purposely wouldn't make any changes to the 'geom' column for that reason.

Comment: @Akina I'm just going through that process now - I'll let you know!

Comment: @Akina I ran the following but didn't seem to change anything. UPDATE schema.table SET column = Substr(column, 1, 5), column2 = Substr(column2, 1, 50)

Comment: If you need to change column definition you must execute `ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN`. [manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-alter.html#id-1.5.4.7.10)